# How to set focus on popup after opening a new page?

Tags: javascript

in my already opened popup, there is a button. When I click on it, it opens a new window with:

```
window.open("http://www.example.com","_blank");// goes to external new page
```

and then my original popup loses focus (it is hidden by the webpage it has just opened)

Is there a way to set the focus back to my original popup ? (to set it back to front)

Answer (score 2):

What about simple `.focus()` method ?

```
window.open("http://www.example.com","_blank").focus();
```

Comment: NOT GOOD ! popup is still behind !

Comment: Assign window handler to variable and call it with delay.

Comment: tried that with no success
  window.open("http://www.example.com","_blank");
  window.blur();
  setTimeout(function() {   
   window.focus();
  },100);

Comment: I checked your fiddle: it just open a new tab and set the focus on the new opened page !  I want the focus to be set BACK to the opener !

Comment: let me explain again: my popup is already opened. Inside there is a button. When I click on it, it opens a NEW page. What I try is to do : I want the original popup back on top (since the new page covers it now !)